# How to add custom Text into Module which can be translated automatically

Tags: php, xml, ini, joomla3.3

I've some code which ends with this:

I'm trying to give the `$note` variable another Joomla intern XML declaration which can be translated automatically beside Joomla (after defining this values in some .ini). I'm working actually at mod_custom (default.php).

```
$note = $db->loadResult();
if ($note =='')
$note = "COM_MODULES_NO_TITLE_RESULT";
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark the question as solved. There's no need to do that in the title, since we're not a forum - the tick mark in the question below does that fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try:

> $note = JText::_('COM_MODULES_NO_TITLE_RESULT');

This official joomla tutorial may help you understand how JTEXT works: [Formatted fields in language translation strings](http://docs.joomla.org/Formatted_fields_in_language_translation_strings)

Comment: i used that snippet of code deleting the old $note="COM_MOD..." and defined the COM_MODULES_NO_TITLE_RESULT in mod_custom.ini and mod_custom_sys.ini but it displays only "COM_MODULES_NO_TITLE_RESULT" not the predefined text

Comment: sorry had to put the predefined text into /language/de-DE and /language/en-EN into the needed ini file (in my case mod_custom.ini)

Comment: Is there a possibility to output something like this 

$note = $module->title AND "-" AND JText::_( 'COM_MODULES_NO_TITLE_RESULT' );

SOLVED ALSO i just echo the other variable later